# Unable to forward emails using Gmail

Tags: gmail, forwarding

I am unable to forward emails from my Gmail. Everything else seems to work fine.
It does not matter what the contents of the message to be forwarded are.

I get this error when I try:

[image]

What should I try in order to be able to forward things again?

Comment: It's likely to be Gmail service disruption. Have a look. http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&ts=1379995199000&sid=1&iid=043f082bc7cd18e15458318035d9bc7a

Comment: Minor service outage and off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, questions regarding specific websites (such as Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, etc) are [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) unless it is specific to how your computer or network connects/interfaces to those websites.

---

Today Google experienced a service outage with email sent out. It began as affecting a small amount of users and later affected around half.

You can check service disruptions for Google's services [on their website](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status&ts=1379979685593).